# C# Timer not changing values of doubles

Tags: c#, timer, double

I have a timer set up and enabled for every 100ms.
However for the life of me I can't work out why the timer is not changing the double values. It's just staying the same. The timer itself works absolutely fine. I believe it's going to be something simple within the timer_tick code itself.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                  
       cords.Text = map.Position.ToString();
        double enemnylat = 51.97840583915594;
        double enemnylng = 0.35796410164283465;
        double friendlylat = 52.19119384412198;
        double friendlylng = 0.93958379542825944;
        PointLatLng enemny = new PointLatLng(enemnylat, enemnylng);
        PointLatLng friendly = new PointLatLng(friendlylat, friendlylng);
        double markerDist = GMap.NET.MapProviders.EmptyProvider.Instance.Projection.GetDistance(enemny, friendly);
       
        if (markerDist == 0)
        {
            miles.Text = "At Destination";
        } else if (markerDist != 0)
        {
            miles.Text = "Miles: " + markerDist.ToString();
            friendlylat = friendlylat - 0.1;
            friendlylng = friendlylng - 0.1;
            if (enemnylat >= friendlylat && enemnylng >= friendlylng)
            {
                friendlylat = friendlylat - 0.1;
                friendlylng = friendlylng - 0.1;

            }
            else if (enemnylat <= friendlylat && enemnylng <= friendlylng)
            {
                friendlylat = friendlylat + 0.1;
                friendlylng = friendlylng + 0.1;
            }
        }
      

    }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] the code in the question to be [mre] - so far it looks like "when I set values to constant on every call those values stay constant on every call" (I know that sounds stupid and almost offensive, so I'm just guessing that the code in the question is different from what you have in your running code and thus does not properly represent the problem you are facing)

Comment: Notice that you declare the variables local to your timer handler. You set them, and then manipulate them in the handler. Maybe I'm missing something, but the only `double`s I see are local to that routine. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is a straight extract from my code.

Comment: @Flydog57 - I’m sure I’ve tried it out of the timer handler, I’ll give it another go though.